# Need suggestion for Image face recognition / detection on web2py

Tags: javascript, image, web2py, face-recognition, face-detection

**Issue**

I am currently doing an image face recognition function on web2py and I am stuck on creating a function on how to it can detect faces from images.

**Brief description of how the function will be working**

Basically, there will be images passed down to the system and the function will have to detect the face on the images, like a boxed up area of the face location on the image.

**Ideal suggestion**

The language I am writing this function on web2py can be in JavaScript / Python and ideally would like it to be in JavaScript so that I am able to understand it as I am not well versed with Python.

If anyone have any suggestion or guide to aid me in this issue, please do so as I am currently blanked out and have no idea how to begin despite researching.

Comment: From your question I don't get the idea that you will be able to do this. This is hard. Better try and find a library that has done this for you, if it exists. This won't be possible in Javascript.

Comment: Okay, trying to find existing libraries right now, if you have any, feel free to toss it out here for me thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can use [OpenCV](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) library for whatever you wanted to also lot of other features.

If you are familiar with AWS [Rekognition](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/) is also a great choice, as you can get both Python and JavaScript as well and also in a lot of other popular languages.